# Refused to display 'url' of website in a !frame

Tags: php, server, joomla, header

I am trying to load the website using iframe but it gives me below error:

"Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."
Please check the Screenshot :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3gMm.png)

Comment: the message doesn't lie to you. X-Frame-Options blocks page loading under the domain

Comment: @WiatroBosy I knew it and I am trying deny the X-frame-option  but it does'nt make any effect on website

Comment: Is this your site? Give me the link. Check the htaccess